# Store time in Java and SQL SERVER

Tags: java, sql-server

I want to store the time in HH: MM format in a variable. It should also be able to be stored in SQL log

Comment: In java you can store a time (without a date) using the `LocalTime` type. SQL Server has the `TIME` data time that serves the same purpose. None of these data types store the time as a String or VARCHAR, though.

Comment: Excellent information. Thanks a lot. I have already solved it as you have indicated.

Answer (score 0):

use the following import,
import java.sql.Time;

```
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Time myTime = new Time(now);
    int hh = myTime.getHours();
    int mm = myTime.getMinutes();
    System.out.printf("%d:%d",hh,mm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved it, as The Impaler has mentioned to me as follows:

```
CallableStatement assignTurn = connectionBBDD.getConexionBBDD ()
.prepareCall ("{call assignTurn (?,?)}");

assignTurn.setTime (1, Time.valueOf (LocalTime .of (8, 0)));
assignTurn.setTime (2, Time.valueOf (LocalTime .of (8, 30)));
assignTurn.execute();
```